# detete the record from list view and in database in xamarin.android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I want to delete record from list view. So I am using long click. On long click a dialog must appear if user enters yes then delete the record. If user press no button then dismiss. The `deleterecord` method is executing but no action taking place.

```
public class ListActivity : Activity
{
    ListView listItems;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle SaveInstace)
    {
        base.OnCreate (SaveInstace);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Listviewlayout);

        //back button
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
        //Gets ListView object instance
        Database sqldb1 = ((GlobalClass)this.Application).sqldb;

        listItems = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);

        GetCursorView ();
        //Add ItemClick event handler to ListView instance
        listItems.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs> (item_Clicked);

        listItems.ItemLongClick+= new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs> (item_longclicked);

    }
```

`my item_clicked` method is here..

```
    public void item_longclicked(object sender,AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Database sqldb1 = ((GlobalClass)this.Application).sqldb;
        TextView shName = e.View.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Name_row);
        TextView shLastName = e.View.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.LastName_row);
        TextView shAge = e.View.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.Age_row);
        int s=e.Position;
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        alert.SetTitle ("Do you want to delete");
        alert.SetPositiveButton ("yes", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)null);
        alert.SetNegativeButton ("No", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)null);
        var dial = alert.Create ();
        dial.Show ();

        //get the buttons
        var yesbtn= dial.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive);
        var nobtn = dial.GetButton ((int)DialogButtonType.Negative);
        yesbtn.Click+=delegate 
        {
            sqldb1.DeleteRecord(s);
            GetCursorView();
        };
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to manually notify your listview that the data in the database has changed. Try restarting your app (actually kill it and open it again) so it reloads the records from the database.

Comment: thank you for the replay...it is working perfectly if i use  _id column but i want to know how to do without representing  id column in my listview.